# How to include two date picker's in one html contact form?

Tags: html

I have tried to developed a simple html contact form and included two date pickers.
one picker is working but other one is not working?
what is the reason behind it? how can i put date pickers to both?

```
    <form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <h1 class="title">Contact</h1>

        <label></label>
        <input name="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Name">

        <label></label>
        <input name="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">

        <label></label>
        <input name="date2" type="text" required="required" id="datepicker" placeholder="Your Arrival">

        <label></label>
        <input name="date" type="text" required="required" id="datepicker" placeholder="Your Date">

        <input id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

</section>
```

Comment: HTML 101: Ids have to be unique within an HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

try a different id for your date field

```
<input name="date2" type="text" required="required" id="datepicker2" placeholder="Your Arrival">

<input name="date" type="text" required="required" id="datepicker" placeholder="Your Date">
```

You should also initiate as a date field your `datepicker2` in your js/jquery script

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
<input type="date" name="dateField1">
<input type="date" name="dateField2">
```